# CSS Vertical Alignment in HTML emails

Tags: css, email, alignment

As we all know, most email clients don't support all [CSS attributes](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/). If I want to vertically align images and text, what's the most compatible means of doing so?

Right now, I'm doing:

```
<img style="position:relative;top:3px;" src="http://url.com/img.jpg" /> <span>Words and stuff</span>
```

This works in some clients, but not all (particularly Gmail). Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate to say it, but `<table>`. CSS `position` is [not supported well](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)